# How can I inject clips [ads] in a playlist every x minutes (even if previous clip is not over)

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, playlists, advertisements

Sorry for the title, I find it quite hard to describe what I want to do in a single sentence

We have a few TV here linked to our computer, which we use to display clips about what we do in our sport center, what you should do to stay in good form ect ... It's running non stop, actually though vlc + playlist. Those main clips are 1-2 hours long and we have about 20 of them looping randomly all day.

We would like to inject ads for some of our sponsiored products every now and then during the playlist, like say one ad every 15 minute.

Does any one know how we can do that, while keeping the main clip random order ?

I thought about encoding the whole thing as a single movie with ads inserted, but then it's not random. So we can put the ads in the playlist itself right ? Except clips are several hours long and we want that more often than that.

Cutting the main clips in several pieces seems to work but that kind of sucks as new clips are made every month.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a project very similar to this in which we we adding commercials into unencrypted video feeds for broadcast.  We were lucky in that there is a tone that once detected we could then play a pre-defined length commercial.

For you to do this in VNC you will really want to write a little script to do this.  Put all the files in one directory and then get a listing of that directory into a file.  From there you should know the length of each video file (just the long ones).  VLC has a command line option for [start-time and stop-time](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help).  A quick script that reads the file, you input the length and number of commercials that you want, and then loop to the next file etc and then when you are done it would have generated a proper play list with all the commercials added.

There is a little work involved but getting it to be randomized etc shouldn't be any big deal.  Also if you wanted you could create a file that you could "mark" the file name and the times you wanted commercials so that they flowed more naturally.